# update same table with condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Unable to execute the trigger, Can anyone explain where i am doing wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HK_WS_ED_CT_T1
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CI On HK_WS_ED_CT
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
      IF (:new.CI = CI) THEN 
       UPDATE HK_WS_ED_CT
      SET (TRANS_OTHER, TRANS_OTHER_DESC) =
     (SELECT TRANS_OTHER, TRANS_OTHER_DESC 
      FROM HK_WS_ED_CT
      where CI = :NEW.CI and rownum <=1 order by DATE)
      end if; 
    END;
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve?  I can't figure out what you'd hope this code would do.

Comment: And errors being shown? I'm sensing mutating table. I think this code could be simplified with better understanding of :NEW & :OLD prefixes

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the table the trigger is on. This is not allowed.
You should put `:new.trans_other` equal to something and `:new.trans_other_desc` to something.

The update of the field will be ok then.

If you really want to update all the rows of that same table you should take a look at compound triggers. But I doubt this is what you want.

The main problem in DB triggers is you can't select, insert, update, delete from the table the trigger is firing on. The table is locked at this moment.